# Checking login user role in razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.Identity.Name=="administrator")
{
     <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="module">
        <ul class="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="mainContent">
             Hello, @User.Identity.Name !
         </div>
     </div>
```

This is my layout if the user is authenticated as administrator but this sort of check looks no good, I need to check the role of the user not his name.

Here is the controler method

```
    public ActionResult AuthenticatedUserLayout(string username) 
    {
        var lst=userContext.UserProfiles.ToList();
        var user = lst.Select(u => u.UserName == username);

        if(IsAdmin(Session["LoginUser"].ToString())) return View(user); else return Index();
    }
```

I also find that `return View(user)` is no good, because I don't know how to make any use of that `user`.

Comment: `@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("administrator"))`

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
{
     <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="module">
           <ul class="menu">
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="mainContent">
             Hello, @User.Identity.Name !
         </div>
     </div>
}
```

Comment: It's pity that not to support Authorize attribute like [Authorize(Role = "Administrator")] or  [Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdministratorRole")]

Comment: @OzanBAYRAM, you can use Authorize Attribute, it just wouldn't be as convenient. A better way may be to carry around a user object with permission.

Comment: Thanks, @dave-alperovich, I noticed that I forgot to add page directive to cshtml file. This is why I could not make it work.

Comment: Is there a way to check this based on Individual Permissions?

Comment: @JordanLeeBurnes, you can only check if user is an Admin

Answer (score 29):

For ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
```

Answer (score 14):

Dave's answer is correct.  I would suggest that you consider using a property on your model called `IsAdministrator` or `CanSeeSidebar` and treat answering that question as **domain logic**.

The view should work only with the model.  Looking at the thread, reading from a database, are the same in respect that they answer domain questions.  All those types of questions should be answered before your controller hands the model off to the view.

Comment: Isn't that hard if you want to put this on a shared view - which with a navigation you almost certainly will?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method that can be done directly on the razor page. You just need access to the UserManager and RoleManager.

Note: My implementation uses custom user and role classes.  If you don't have custom user or role classes, then replace all instances of <User> with <IdentityUser> and <Role> with <IdentityRole>.

This provides the ability to have direct access to the actual role object for each assigned role within the razor page which is helpful if you have custom fields attached to the role like I have.

```
@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<User> UserManager
@inject RoleManager<Role> RoleManager

@{
    List<Role> UserRoles = null;

    if(SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)){
        UserRoles = (from Role R in RoleManager.Roles.ToList() where User.IsInRole(R.Name) select R).ToList();
    }
}

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    //Show the user's role(s)'
    @if (UserRoles != null)
    {
        @foreach (Role Role in UserRoles)
        {
            <p>@Role.Name</p>
        }
    }
} else
{
    <p>Please log in</p>
}
```