# Custom authorization in Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, role-base-authorization

I am currently working on a C# MVC project. I used `CustomAuthorizationAttribute` to authorize every user in my project.

I have 3 Roles : Super Admin, Admin and User

While creating a new user there is an option for adding the corresponding Role, and it can be edited (The person with 'User' Role can not add or edit users).

To set up this authentication I created two tables, '*PermissionFunction*' and '*Permission*' respectively. The Table details is given below :

***PermissionFunction***:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|   PermFunc_ID       |     bigint       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|   PermFunc_Name     |     varchar(50)  |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

***Permission***:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|   Perm_ID           |      bigint      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|   Perm_RollID       |      bigint      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|   Perm_PermFuncID   |      bigint      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

*PermFunc_ID* and *Perm_ID* are Primary key for the tables respectively. *PermFunc_Name* is the name referring each action in all controllers. *Permission* Table contains Foreign Key for both *Role* and *PermissionFunction* tables.

For reference here is my **Role** table :

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|   Rol_ID            |    bigint        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|   Rol_Name          |    varchar(50)   |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

---

For authentication I added a class *CustomAuthorizationAttribute* and added authorization attribute to every controller action.

For example consider my *PermissionFunction* table vales as below:

```
|---------------------|-------------------|
|   PermFunc_ID       |    PermFunc_Name  |
|---------------------|-------------------|
|       1             |    userIndex      |
|---------------------|-------------------|
|       2             |    userCreate     |
|---------------------|-------------------|
```

and my *HomeController* :

```
public class UserController : Controller
{

    [CustomAuthorization(IdentityRoles = "userIndex")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [CustomAuthorization(IdentityRoles = "userCreate")]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

and the *CustomAuthorizationAttribute* class :

```
public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private PermissionRepository _permission = new PermissionRepository();
    private PermissionFuncRepository _permissionFun = new PermissionFuncRepository();

    // roles start
    public string IdentityRoles
    {
        get { return _permissionName ?? String.Empty; }
        set { _permissionName = value; }
    }

    private string _permissionName;

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //do the base class AuthorizeCore first
        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string RoleID = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(httpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name.Split('|')[1];

            var permisionID = _permissionFun.FindByName(_permissionName);

            if(permisionID != null)
            {
                var permis = _permission.GetPermission().Where(a => a.Perm_PermFuncID == permisionID.PermFunc_ID && a.Perm_RollID.ToString() == RoleID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (permis != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }
        return false;

    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        //if the user is not logged in use the deafult HandleUnauthorizedRequest and redirect to the login page
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        //if the user is logged in but is trying to access a page he/she doesn't have the right for show the access denied page
        else
        {
            // the controller action was invoked with an AJAX request
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/AccessDeniedNew");
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/AccessDenied");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is working fine.

---

**My Question**

---

This is my *Index* html :

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-rounded btn-success" type="button" id ="CreateButton" onclick="UserCreate()"> Create New User </button> // create new user

   .....   // code continues

// code for modal popup
<div id="edit-user" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function UserCreate() {
        var url = "/User/Create/";
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#edit-user').html(data);
                $('#edit-user').modal('show');
           });
    }
</script>
```

When *CreateButton* clicks a modal popup comes for adding details and create a new user.

---

> Is there any way I could hide the create new button if the user has no access to create a new user.? ( ie: If the *userCreate* is not in the *PermissionFunction* Table).

Answer (score 0):

You can check permissions and add button to the page if needed. You already know the way to get permission information, so you can store some information in `ViewData` or `ViewBag` and check if create button should be there. The information can be just a simple `boolean`. It will be something like this

```
@if(ViewBag.CanCreate)
{
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-rounded btn-success" type="button" id ="CreateButton" onclick="UserCreate()"> Create New User </button>
}
```

where `CanCreate` you can set from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you take idea from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981853/asp-net-mvc3-razor-display-actionlink-based-on-user-role)

However the solution is not very elegant, you could create your own action link like

```
@html.AuthorizeActionLink("button name","your action/controller name","your security role")
```

I think you could even get rid of the last parameter and automatically check on connected user and rights required on the action you are calling to chose to display it or not.

If you really need specific html then I suggest the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969167/checking-login-user-role-in-razor-page)
It is easier if you want to handle multiple access rights on one page. Indeed Viewbags will start to be a pain if you have many of them to manage.

Hope this helps

regards

Edit : for implemention the authorizeActionLink I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197551/how-to-hide-action-link-if-user-has-no-rights-to-action)