# How to display HTML element when user is logged in. (ASP.NET Core MVC, without EF)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, session-state

I've got an simple login system. Whenever a user is logged in, I want them to see a specific HTML div. Only if you've logged in. For the users that haven't logged in, I want this element to be hidden. I've read something about "roles" but I don't know if this was the right concept to apply in this situation. Could someone give me advice about how I could fix this problem.

Comment: How have you implemented logins? Are you using the ASP.NET Core Identity API? Are you using one of the build in Authentication schemes?

Answer (score 0):

This link should show you how to check authentication and roles in the Razor page.

[Checking Login and Roles In Razor Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969167/checking-login-user-role-in-razor-page)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Identity you could check utilize on this

```
    User.Identity.Name;
    User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

If you are using custom (cookie) authentication, you can also leverage read/write the user inside the cookie. Put it on Viewbag or direct access it on the Razor page.

For more information and/or external login providers, you can check this out bro https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: User or User.Identity is not part of EF. You could try typing it on a new project.